# how to get dropdown selected value and not text while submitting form in django views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[i have a dropdown list which you can see on left side. i want to fetch the value of dropdown in my views.py but when i cleaned_data['city'] it gives me the text of the selected value and not the value . how can i get this? can anyone help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvegk.png)

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

from .validator import validate_age
# Create your models here.


class City(models.Model):
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name



class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_age])
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def clean(self):
        if self.name:
            self.name =self.name.strip()
```

`views.py`

```
def employee(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            pan_number = form.cleaned_data['pan_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
            print(city)

            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.callproc('insert_employee', [name, pan_number, age,  gender, email,  city])

            # qs_add = Employee(name=name, pan_number=pan_number, email=email, age=age, city=city, gender=gender)
            # qs_add.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Employee save successfully')
            context['form'] = context['form'] = EmployeeForm()

        else:
            context['form'] = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
    else:
        context['form'] = EmployeeForm()
    
    return render(request, 'app/employee.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you please add your EmployeeForm definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model `Employee` the field `city` is a `ForeignKey` for which the default form field is [`ModelChoiceField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). This form field normalizes to *a model instance*. Assuming that you don't use some other form field you are not getting the choice text but an instance of `City`. Therefore you can simply write `city.id` or `city.pk` to get the id that you want, or you can simply write the follows:

```
city = form.cleaned_data['city'].pk
```

Also calling some procedure to insert values should not really be needed (unless for some reason you really want to save bandwidth), assuming you use a `ModelForm` you can simply write the follows to save the employee to the database:

```
employee = form.save()
```

Comment: ya i know that . but it was a task assigned to me. to call store procedure to insert values into database .